# Can anyone recommend a synthetic data generator?

Tags: database

Did anyone come across a free data generator that can create synthetic data to load into databases for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at other questions I stumbled on Benerator, http://databene.org/databene-benerator.html. I haven't tried it, but:

apparently comes with these JDBC drivers
http://databene.org/databene-benerator/112-installing-the-benerator-distribution.html
• jTDS Driver (MS SQL Server or Sybase)
• MySQL Connector
• HSQL DB
•  Derby Client
• PostgreSQL
• Jaybird (Firebird DB) 
you can of course install more (e.g. Oracle) yourself...

Comment: For the Benerator web site I get an "Access denied." message

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any free products to recommend, but if you are willing to purchase a commercial license, I can recommend ExactData's [Dynamic Data Generator](http://www.exactdata.net/products-and-services/dynamic-data-generator%E2%84%A2/). It attempts to  produce large scale, synthetic, realistic, and engineered data sets. It allows you to model the data sets for your tests, customize the output format (CSV, for instance), and then generate an large numbers of internally consistent data records.

I can recommend the DDG because I am a developer on this product.

Answer (score 0):

As you know your data better than anyone outside your organization, you would probably get the best results by writing code yourself to do this. It would be fairly straightforward to write a small program in C#, Python, etc to generate test data.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at my FOSS [data generator](http://code.google.com/p/csvtest/) - this is kind of a proof of concept at the moment, but is useable.

Answer (score 0):

[Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) has a tool to do exactly this.  I fooled around a little with the trial and thought it had potential.  It does cost $$ so it may not suit your current needs.

Comment: not worth if you are looking for synthetic data. ok if you want random/junk data quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and used the Redgate tool, it is part of the Redgate Toolbelt bundle, and I can recommend it.  Very nice tool with lots of possibilities.  It however costs money as peacedog pointed out, if you are doing database development on consistent basis it is very much worth it.

Comment: It looks like it works only with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @uthark ~ I didn't think RedGate made any bones about being a Microsoft oriented shop ... Besides, what's the problem with MSSQL? Cheaper than Oracle, found in lots of shops...

Comment: @drachenstern - I use MySQL and PostgreSQL at work a lot.

Comment: @uthark ~ I had surmised that from your comment.

Answer (score -1):

to generate synthetic transactional datasets you can use IBM Synthetic data generator. but I suggest you to download Iranshamim Synthetic dataset generator, because it has GUI and generates more accurate results.